# Spring bind different properties files to different beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

It's my MySQL properties file

mysql.properties

```
dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
hbm2ddl_method=validate
show_sql=true
format_sql=false
pool_name=testpool
jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
minimum_idle=2
uname=root
password=testpsw
cache_prep_stmts=true
prep_stmt_cache_size=256
prep_stmt_cache_sql_limit=2048
use_server_prep_stmts=true
maximum_pool_size=30
driver_class_name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and Oracle properties file for datasource configuration.

```
dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hbm2ddl_method=validate
show_sql=true
format_sql=false
pool_name=testpool
jdbc_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testdb
minimum_idle=2
uname=barn_act
password=testpsw
cache_prep_stmts=true
prep_stmt_cache_size=256
prep_stmt_cache_sql_limit=2048
use_server_prep_stmts=true
maximum_pool_size=30
driver_class_name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I created two classes like this to bind properties into fields.

```
@Component("mysql_props")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/mysql.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class HibernateMySQLProperties {

    private String dialect;
    //other props

}


@Component("oracle_props")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/oracle.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class HibernateOracleProperties {
//same fileds as mysql
}
```

When I inject these two beans to PersistenceConfiguration class same propety fields are injected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ HibernateOracleProperties.class, HibernateMySQLProperties.class })
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracle_props")
    private HibernateOracleProperties oracleProps;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mysql_props")
    private HibernateMySQLProperties mysqlProps;
}
```

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem/behavior in spring prior to spring-boot. In spring property placeholder can understand unique key. Your both properties file has same name of keys.

So the solution would be like below with fewer changes.

Change the property file like below. 
mysql.properties

```
mysql.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
****** all otheres same start with mysql.
```

Oracle properties file

```
oracle.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
 ****** all otheres same start with oracle.
```

Now change your Hibernate*Properties.java @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

```
@Component("oracle_props")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/oracle.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle")


@Component("mysql_props")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/mysql.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql")
```

No need of any change in PersistenceConfig.java file.